# How to prevent `scrapy` from decoding local url-encoded filenames?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I have some webpages saved locally, whose names are url-encoded using `urllib.parse.quote` as follows:

```
https%3A%2F%2Fwebsite.com%2Flist%2F27-6.html
```

When using `scrapy` to extract information from these web pages, it reports error:

```
DEBUG: Retrying <GET file:///local_dir/https%3A%2F%2Fwebsite.com%2Flist%2F27-6.html> (failed 2 times): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/local_dir/https:/website.com/list/27-6.html'
```

It seems `scrapy` unquote my file names. I tried following setting. It doesn't work.

```
custom_settings = {
    'FILES_URLS_FIELD': 'file_urls',
    'FILES_RESULT_FIELD': 'files',
    'FILES_URLS_FILENAME_FIELD': None,
}
```

Comment: As the error says, at `/local_dir/https:/website.com/list/` path, there is no `27-6.html` file. Check your `saving file code` and print out where it is getting saved through the code again.

Comment: @shaikmoeed my files are saved at `/local_dir`, 'https:/website.com/list' is part of the file name, which is encoded using `urllib.parse.quote` as `https%3A%2F%2Fwebsite.com%2Flist%2F27-6.html`

Comment: I suggest to replace `/` with `_` and store it, and use the same logic while reading it as well.